# CSS - how to create these separators?

Tags: html, css, separator

I have a css homework to copy exactly a web site. I've done about 80% of my work but there're still some elements in the original website that i can't bring to my copy, for example, these separators:

[image]

I've tried some ways on the Internet but none of them seems to work with my current situation.
This is my work until now: https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/178536659/xin/index.html.

Besides that, my teacher provided us some resources (included logos, images etc... to make a copy of the website). It includes some transparent-only horizontal rectangle images. I dont' know what it is used for ... Is it use for make these separators, i guess ?

So I hope you guys could help me with this ... any comments would be appreciated. Thanks so much in advanced !

Comment: use padding and background images.

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways to create vertical separators, the most common border-left/border-right or pseudo elements :before and :after, horizontal separators are made with <hr> tag.

---

Borders documentation:

http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_border.asp

Here are some good examples with pseudo-elements (which you can use with your images):

http://krasimirtsonev.com/blog/article/CSS-before-and-after-pseudo-elements-in-practice

You can also create divs, give them css properties to emulate a separator and place them in between or use images.

Answer (score 0):

They are simple borders, such as

```
ul#nav_menu li {
  border-right: 1px solid #cecece;
}
```

Now remove the border of the first child from the element using some class or id and setting no border to it! Simple.

Answer (score 0):

Use this in your CSS. I think it will work for you.

#header ul li{border-right:2px solid #d8d8d8;}
#header ul li:last-child{border:none;}